# What's the best way to turn a bunch of XML docs into a set of HTML help pages, run locally?

Tags: html, xml, documentation

My intent to is to create documentation for our software project that is checked into our SCM system along with the source code.

These files can be spread among various sub-projects but I want to bring the documentation together so that, e.g. a page can include documentation on more than one sub-project at once.  The viewer should not see a 'page per sub-project' - rather they see the documentation for the project and not the boundaries between sub-projects.

This documentation needs to load direct from a user's local PC in their browser, so I can't composite or transform XML files into a single HTML on a server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing I would suggest to transform XML into another form would be XSLT http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/.

> XSL stands for EXtensible Stylesheet Language, and is a style sheet language for XML documents.
>
> XSLT stands for XSL Transformations. In this tutorial you will learn how to use XSLT to transform XML documents into other formats, like XHTML.

Comment: Yeah. I'd need to run the transforms offline I guess (it violates certain browsers' security constraints to load another local file from an HTML file, which precludes doing the transform on-the-fly in the browser I think).